# SetSrc in iframe with multiple links to multiple sources

Tags: javascript, iframe

apologies in advanced if I use the wrong terminology or if this is obvious to solve. I'm trying to expand on this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetSrc() 
{
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src = document.getElementById("iframelink").value;
}
</script>
```

To allow multiple src links to be loaded with different buttons as in this 
Html:

```
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="page1.html" width="900" height="600" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <table>
    <tr>    
        <td><button value="page1.html" id="iframelink" onclick="SetSrc()"><p>image1</p><img src="thumb1.jpg" title=""/></button></td>
        <td><button value="page2.html" id="iframelink" onclick="SetSrc()"><p>image2</p><img src="thumb2.jpg"/></button></td>
        <td><button value="page3.html" id="iframelink" onclick="SetSrc()"><p>image3</p><img src="thumb3.jpg"/></button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I've put the first link into the iframe element(?) as I want the page to start with a page loaded into the iframe.

I'm using this to load images for a gallery in which I'm also using a toggle_visibility to show/hide categories the buttons are placed into and a jQuery zoom script within the page the iframe links to. The script as it is works fine to load from page1.html to another (i.e. page2.html) and doesn't seem to conflict with the other zoom or toggle scripts.

Comment: Can't seem to edit (just get avast pop-up saying this site is safe on hovering over edit link). I just wanted to add a 3rd button/page link to make it clear that I need it to work for more then 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **HTML IDs must be unique**

Change Your HTML as, pass `this` invoker object to method

```
  <button value="page1.html" onclick="SetSrc(this)">
```

JS Method

```
function SetSrc(obj) {
    document.getElementById("myIframe").src =obj.value;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jAs4t/), In demo simple alerts buttons value

### EDIT

Aboove will work, but I suggest you to don't use inline event binding like  `onclick="SetSrc(this)"`

*HTML*

```
<button value="page1.html" class="myButton">button1</button>
<button value="page2.html" class="myButton">button2</button>
<button value="page3.html" class="myButton">button3</button>
```

*JavaScript*

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myButton');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("myIframe").src =
            this.value;
        }
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Ujm5p/)

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, I wasn't expecting it to be such a short script, thank you.

Comment: it seems to work fine, but I'll wait a day to see if anyone has anything to add, thanks again

Comment: That works too. Just to ask, is that because inline event binding/'this' would then conflict with another script if using the same term/'this' again? if it's not easy to explain to someone new to scripting no worries.

Comment: @trible, I didn't get you. but `this` is a special keyword. In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called

Comment: @trible, there are couple of good articles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html and http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/. Explaining this in comment section is quite difficult